# Compute the maximal proper submodule of $Z\left(\frac{1}{2}\alpha\right)$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, representation-theory, lie-algebras

Let $\alpha$ be the positive root of the Lie algebra $sl(2,F)$, where $F$ is algebraically closed, of characteristic $0$.

I think the verma module $Z\left(\frac{1}{2}\alpha\right)$ should have this weight space decomposition:
$$Z\left(\frac{1}{2}\alpha\right)=\bigoplus_{n=0}^\infty V_{\frac{1}{2}\alpha-n\alpha} \quad \text{ for } \ \ \  V_{\frac{1}{2}\alpha-n\alpha}=\text{Span}(y^nv^+)$$

Since $\frac{1}{2}\alpha$ is a dominant integral weight, the quotient of the maximal proper submodule should be finite dimensional. But I can't figure out what the max submodule is, since $Z\left(\frac{1}{2}\alpha\right)$ seems irreducible to me. Could someone show me how to determine the max submodule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: The irreducible finite-dimensional representation you want to find as quotient of this Verma module is the $2$-dimensional one with weights $\pm\frac{1}{2}\alpha$.

To get there, use $h v =(xy-yx)v$ to show inductively that for $ w \in V_{\frac12\alpha-n\alpha}$, we have $x w = n(2-n) w'$ for some $w' \in V_{\frac12\alpha-(n-1)\alpha}$. So what is $x v$ for $v \in V_{-\frac32 \alpha}$? Can you now see an invariant submodule of codimension $2$? (Compare also [this section of the WP article on Verma modules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verma_module#The_case_of_%7F%27%22%60UNIQ--postMath-0000003A-QINU%60%22%27%7F), just adapt the notation.)

Comment: By induction: $0=xv^+=0(-2)v^+$ 

$xy^nv^+=hy^{n-1}v^+yxy^{n-1}v^+=(3-2n)y^{n-1}v^+(n-1)(3-n)y^{n-1}v^+=n(2-n)y^{n-1}v^+$

Therefore $xy^2v^+=0$, thus $\bigoplus_{n=2}^\infty V_{\frac{1}{2}\alpha-n\alpha}$ is a maximal subrepresentation, since $xy^2=2(2-2)yv^+=0$